# Add js logic to external web components

Tags: polymer

I started to use web components from bower recently in my applications. I am trying to tweak a small logic in a particular web component.  I want to know is there a way we can change the js logic specific to a component in my local js file instead of forking a repository and try to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For quick hacks you can go to `bower_components` and experiment. For persistent changes you will need a fork.

Of course you could try monkey-patching by replacing methods/functions but it's ugly and brittle in case the dependency library changes.